# Mobile stacking for dotmailer 3 column easy editor - doesn't work on iphone

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design, dotmailer

I'm using `Dotmailer`'s easy editor to create a responsive template and all was going well until I hit the 3 column element I need to stack. It just refuses to render properly on iPhone! Code below, ideas please!

```html
<table class="ee_element ee_borders ee_contains_bdr" style="table-layout: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="600"><tbody><tr><td class="ee_pad ee_bdr" style="padding: 0px; border-top-color: rgb(29, 44, 112); border-top-width: 4px; border-top-style: solid;"><table class="eebdrtbl" style="table-layout: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td class="eeb_width" style="width: 600px;"><table width="100%" class="ee_spacer eev_element" style="width: 600px; table-layout: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="600" ee-type="element"><tbody><tr><td style="padding: 0px; width: 600px; font-size: 1px;"><img width="10" height="5" style="display: block;" alt="" src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/t/s.gif"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table><table width="100%" class="ee_columns ee_element" style="width: 600px; position: relative; table-layout: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-edit="columns" data-eewidth="600" ee-type="container" data-title="3 columns">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td width="33%" align="left" class="ee_dropzone ved-scaled-cols" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;"><table width="100%" class="ee_element" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194" ee-type="element">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;">
            <img width="194" height="194" class="ee_editable vedpw194" style="width: 194px; height: 194px; display: block;" alt="" src="https://scaler.ddglib.com/vedimage/cmpimg/2010/21170/1633999_20111014_caldene.jpg?w=194&amp;cid=5528741&amp;uid=21170" border="0"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table><table class="ee_element ee_borders eeb_width" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="ee_pad" style="padding: 5px; width: auto;">
            <div class="ee_editable eev_element" style="width: 184px; position: static;" ee-type="element"><p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center;"><a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">Equilibrium&nbsp;Stretch &amp; Flex Bandages</a></p><div style="font-family: trebuchet ms, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;"><p style="margin: 0px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;"><a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(149, 13, 51); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">£39.95</a></p></div></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table></td>
    <td width="8" class="eegap" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; width: 9px;"><img width="8" height="10" style="display: block;" src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/t/s.gif"></td>
    <td width="33%" align="left" class="ee_dropzone ved-scaled-cols" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;"><table width="100%" class="ee_element" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194" ee-type="element">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;">
            <img width="194" height="194" class="ee_editable vedpw194" style="width: 194px; height: 194px; display: block;" alt="" src="https://scaler.ddglib.com/vedimage/cmpimg/2010/21170/1634030_20111014_silverwood.jpg?w=194&amp;cid=5528741&amp;uid=21170" border="0"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table><table class="ee_element ee_borders eeb_width" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="ee_pad" style="padding: 5px; width: auto;">
            <div class="ee_editable eev_element" style="width: 184px;" ee-type="element"> <p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;"> <!-- Remember to change the link within the href "" --> <a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">Equilibrium Stretch &amp; Flex Bandages</a></p><p style="margin: 0px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;"><a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(149, 13, 51); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">£39.95</a></p> </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table></td>
    <td width="8" class="eegap" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; width: 9px;"><img width="8" height="10" style="display: block;" src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/t/s.gif"></td>
    <td width="33%" align="left" class="ee_dropzone ved-scaled-cols" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;"><table width="100%" class="ee_element" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194" ee-type="element">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;">
            <img width="194" height="194" class="ee_editable vedpw194" style="width: 194px; height: 194px; display: block;" alt="" src="https://scaler.ddglib.com/vedimage/cmpimg/2010/21170/1634013_20111014_headcollars.jpg?w=194&amp;cid=5528741&amp;uid=21170" border="0"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table><table class="ee_element ee_borders eeb_width" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="ee_pad" style="padding: 5px; width: auto;">
            <div class="ee_editable eev_element" style="width: 184px;" ee-type="element"><p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center;"><a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">Equilibrium&nbsp;Stretch &amp; Flex Bandages</a></p><div style="font-family: trebuchet ms, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;"><p style="margin: 0px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;"><a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(149, 13, 51); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">£39.95</a></p></div></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **For anybody using the old Dotmailer templates prior to June 2017**
>
> **Support: Android <4.4 & iOS**

Below is a fix for the 3 column blocks for Dotmailer. For stacking to work there are classes that will need to be placed on your table so iOS can read it.

You will also all your emails will need the meta tag that will make emails responsive

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

What i have done below is change the TD to TH and added classes to those TH's so when media query is read it will break it into rows. Android dropped support for display block on TD some 3 years ago but still reads display block on TH. One drawback for TH is the text are bold, so to cater for that i have placed in CSS (`font-weight`) that will unbold the text.

```css
 @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .wrapper{width:100% !important;}
  .ee_element td{text-align:center !important;}
  th.Colms {display:block !important; width:100% !important;}
  .CenteredTable{margin:0 auto;}
 }
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="ee_columns ee_element wrapper" style="width: 600px; position: relative; table-layout: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-edit="columns" data-eewidth="600" ee-type="container" data-title="3 columns">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th width="33%" align="center" class="ee_dropzone ved-scaled-cols Colms" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;margin:0px;padding:0px; font-weight:normal;"><table width="100%" class="ee_element CenteredTable" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194" ee-type="element">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;" class="hundred">
            <img width="194" height="194" class="ee_editable vedpw194" style="width: 194px; height: 194px; display: block;" alt="" src="https://scaler.ddglib.com/vedimage/cmpimg/2010/21170/1633999_20111014_caldene.jpg?w=194&amp;cid=5528741&amp;uid=21170" border="0"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table><table class="ee_element ee_borders eeb_width" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="ee_pad" style="padding: 5px; width: auto;">
            <div class="ee_editable eev_element" style="width: 184px; position: static;" ee-type="element"><p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center;"><a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">Equilibrium&nbsp;Stretch &amp; Flex Bandages</a></p><div style="font-family: trebuchet ms, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;"><p style="margin: 0px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;"><a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(149, 13, 51); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">£39.95</a></p></div></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table></th>
    <th width="8" class="eegap Colms" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; width: 9px;margin:0px;padding:0px; font-weight:normal;"><img width="8" height="10" style="display: block;" src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/t/s.gif"></th>
    <th width="33%" align="left" class="ee_dropzone ved-scaled-cols Colms" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;margin:0px;padding:0px; font-weight:normal;"><table width="100%" class="ee_element CenteredTable" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194" ee-type="element">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;">
            <img width="194" height="194" class="ee_editable vedpw194" style="width: 194px; height: 194px; display: block;" alt="" src="https://scaler.ddglib.com/vedimage/cmpimg/2010/21170/1634030_20111014_silverwood.jpg?w=194&amp;cid=5528741&amp;uid=21170" border="0"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table><table class="ee_element ee_borders eeb_width CenteredTable" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="ee_pad" style="padding: 5px; width: auto;">
            <div class="ee_editable eev_element" style="width: 184px;" ee-type="element"> <p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;"> <!-- Remember to change the link within the href "" --> <a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">Equilibrium Stretch &amp; Flex Bandages</a></p><p style="margin: 0px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;"><a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(149, 13, 51); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">£39.95</a></p> </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table></th>
    <th width="8" class="eegap Colms" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; width: 9px;margin:0px;padding:0px; font-weight:normal;"><img width="8" height="10" style="display: block;" src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/t/s.gif"></th>
    <th width="33%" align="left" class="ee_dropzone ved-scaled-cols Colms" valign="top" style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;margin:0px;padding:0px; font-weight:normal;"><table width="100%" class="ee_element CenteredTable" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194" ee-type="element">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 0px; width: 194px;">
            <img width="194" height="194" class="ee_editable vedpw194" style="width: 194px; height: 194px; display: block;" alt="" src="https://scaler.ddglib.com/vedimage/cmpimg/2010/21170/1634013_20111014_headcollars.jpg?w=194&amp;cid=5528741&amp;uid=21170" border="0"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table><table class="ee_element ee_borders eeb_width CenteredTable" style="width: 194px; table-layout: auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" data-eewidth="194">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="ee_pad" style="padding: 5px; width: auto;">
            <div class="ee_editable eev_element" style="width: 184px;" ee-type="element"><p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center;"><a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">Equilibrium&nbsp;Stretch &amp; Flex Bandages</a></p><div style="font-family: trebuchet ms, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;"><p style="margin: 0px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p style="margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: rgb(29, 44, 112); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 16px;"><a style="text-align: center; color: rgb(149, 13, 51); line-height: 20px; font-family: times, times new roman, serif; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.derbyhouse.co.uk/Equestrian/Horse/Horse+Boots++Safety/Bandages+and+Pads/Equilibrium+Stretch++Flex+Bandages_311-0057.htm?utm_source=INSERT_SOURCE_NAME_HERE&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=INSERT_CAMPAIGN_NAME_HERE">£39.95</a></p></div></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
   </th>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

If there are any questions/issues please hit me up.

Cheers